# SOS: Texture is not drawn perfectly

Tags: directx, textures, alpha, mask, directx-9

Here is my code.

```
m_pApp->m_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0,D3DTSS_COLORARG1,D3DTA_TEXTURE);
m_pApp->m_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0,D3DTSS_COLORARG2,D3DTA_DIFFUSE);
m_pApp->m_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0,D3DTSS_COLOROP,D3DTOP_MODULATE);
m_pApp->m_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(1,D3DTSS_COLORARG1,D3DTA_TEXTURE);
m_pApp->m_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(1,D3DTSS_COLORARG2,D3DTA_CURRENT);
m_pApp->m_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(1,D3DTSS_COLOROP,D3DTOP_ADD);
```

Texture 0 does not have any alpha information. I want to give alpha value 0 to the color vertex whose value is higher than 0x88. I also want to give value 1 to the vertex whose value is lower than 0x88.

I don't know about texture mask effect.

Comment: I'm looking a way about Stencil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, Yes.
The problem was linked to light.
after I set Light the texture was displayed successfully.